# Trying to get table and panels aligned in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get four `panels` on the right side of the screen with a `table` on the left side of those. My issue is when the `table` is not long "tall" enough the `panels` move under the `table` instead of staying on the left side. I am using a bootstrap theme.

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Start Of Projects Table -->
    <div class="col-lg-8 pull-right">
       <!--table-->
    </div>
    <!-- End of projects table -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left settings"> 
       <!--Panel Code -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left settings"> 
       <!--Panel Code -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left settings"> 
       <!--Panel Code-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left settings"> 
       <!--Panel Code-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include all of your code, including the CSS on your page, which will affect the way everything is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you should use the table inside div element and for the 4 panels you should use another "row".

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 pull-right">
   <!-- Start Of Projects Table -->
   <!--table-->
   <!-- End of projects table -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left settings">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12 pull-left settings">
        <!--Panel Code -->
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12 pull-left settings"> 
        <!--Panel Code -->
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12 pull-left settings"> 
        <!--Panel Code-->
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12 pull-left settings"> 
        <!--Panel Code-->
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make parents divs there. Something like this:

```
 <div class="row">
   <div style="float:left; width:50%;">
     <div class="col-lg-8 pull-right">
       <!--table-->
     </div>
   </div>
   <div style="float:right; width:50%;">
     <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left settings"> 
       <!--Panel Code -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left settings"> 
       <!--Panel Code -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left settings"> 
       <!--Panel Code-->
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left settings"> 
       <!--Panel Code-->
     </div>
   </div>
</div><!--End of Row-->
```

Bootstrap does have a class. If i remember is `class="col"` this way you make columns inside that row.and also can be fully responsive. Check this basic tamplates. It will help you understand a little bit more. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template